# How to list files in a directory that have a certain string that appears more than X times

Tags: linux, string

I am trying to search a set of directories and list files where a certain string appears more than X times.

For instance I want to search /home/userX/files (and all subdirectories) and list all files where the string "uploads" occurs more than 10 times.

Ideally an output like this would be awesome:

```
/home/userX/files/file1:15
/home/userX/files/file2:34
/home/userX/files/file3:67
```

where the :xx is the string count in that file... but this final count wouldn't be necessary... only a nice-to-have.

I have figured out how to find files with a certain string, count strings in single files, and list files where a string occurs but have not been able to put these all together... and now I am just totally flustered and confused...

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: The files are on a linux host.  ... so anything that can run on this host I guess... I'm not too picky.  Bash shell type stuff, php, perl, etc.

Comment: Once you have the `pieces of the puzzle`, you can simply put them together by assigning them to a single variable. (e.g. `myline="${filepath}/${filename}:${filenum}"`.

Answer (score 1):

I now have something I am happy with:

```
grep -Hcri uploads * | awk -F ':' -e '$2>10  {print}'
```

This still ignores multiple occurances of 'uploads' per line, but it should be reasonably fast.

- `-H` means that the filename is preserved,
- `-c` means that it should just count the number of lines
- `-r` is for recursive
- `-i` for case-insensitive

It passes the output to `awk` which splits each line along the colon (`-F ':'`) and if the second value is larger than 10, it prints the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edited based on comments):

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -o [STRING] | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq -c | awk '$1>=X {print;}'
```

Replace [STRING] with the string you want to search for and X with the number of times you want it to appear. In your example:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -o uploads | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq -c | awk '$1>=10 {print;}'
```

Comment: With `grep uploads *` you are grepping all files in the current directory again every time `xargs` starts a new process.

Comment: I think you can add `-type f` to the `find` part to get rid of grep error messages that it is a directory, and remove the asterisk in the `grep` command (`xargs` should append the file list anyway).

Comment: I am not quite sure why you have the `grep "./"` part in there.

Comment: Also what's with the `grep "./"`? When would a slash not be preceded by another character in the output? And if this is really necessary, why don't you refactor it into the Awk script it pipes into?

Comment: Without the grep "./" it listed twice any files in the current directory.

Comment: Now that you have removed the asterisk, it should work without that `grep "./"`.

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution involves a small script that allows the user to specify the `search term`, the `minimum occurrences per file` and the `search path`. It then collects the `/absolute/path/to/file:matches` for files where `search term` occurs greater than, or equal to, `occurs` number of times in the file, saving all matching files in an array for whatever later use you need. For purposes of this example it simply prints the search criteria and matching files contained in the array:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -eq 3 ] || {                   ## test for sufficient input
    printf "error: insufficient input:  usage:  %s term occurs path\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

[ $2 -eq $2 >/dev/null 2>&1 ] || {  ## test that 'occur' is an integer value
    printf "error: invalid input:  occurs '%s' is not an integer value!\n" "$2"
    printf "\n  usage: %s term occurs path\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

[ -d "$3" ] || {                   ## test path is a valid directory
    printf "error: invalid input:  path '%s' is not a valid directory!\n" "$3"
    printf "\n  usage: %s term occurs path\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

srchterm="$1"       ## assignment of arguments to variables
occur=$2
srchpath="$3"

declare -a array    ## declare array to hold values

## for each file containing $srchterm
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do 
    [ "${line##*:}" -ge $occur ] &&                       ## test it occurs >= occur
        array+=( "$(realpath "${line%:*}"):${line##*:}" ) ## if so add it to array
done < <(grep -r -c "$srchterm" "$srchpath"/* )           ## grep -r -c to provides files

## output search information
printf "\nsearch term : %s\noccurrances : %d\nsearch path : %s\n\n" \
"$srchterm" $occur "$srchpath"
printf "number of matching files : %d\n\n" ${#array[@]}

for i in "${array[@]}"; do  ## output matching files
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
done

exit 0
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash srchterminfile.sh char 10 .

search term : char
occurrances : 10
search path : .

number of matching files : 77

/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/arginfo.c:16
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/bin_chs_test.c:19
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/binprntst.c:42
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/binprnverif.c:12
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/bookmgr.c:17
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/censorwds.c:11
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/ch+13.c:14
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/ch13str.c:20
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/chkendian.c:16
/home/david/dev/src-c/tmp/concatwords.c:17
<snip>
```

**Note:** if you do not need to save the matching files in an array for later use, you can simply remove the array and replace it with a `printf` or `echo` statement to simply output the lines. I understood you wanted to combine and save the matching filenames and occurrence data within your script.